# Can't access appstoreconnect.apple.com

Tags: app-store-connect

I've registered a new apple id, purchased a membership in Apple Developer Programm as individual.
And i've already have access to https://developer.apple.com/account/#/overview/{my_account_number_here}
[image]

On screenshot above, when I press "Appstore Connect", it redirects me to https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/gettingstarted

[image]

If I press Apps (Приложения) , it redirects me to the tutorial and enrollement, but I've already have bought a developer membership!

So the result is: I have a developer access, but can't upload apps to appstoreconnect. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Called an apple support. They told me that problem is with my address and they are resolving this.